Intellij duplicate parent folder name
Itellij is that when I create a new project from the page (spring initialize) and start the project and create more folders, the name of the original package is duplicated, here is a photo:
enter image description here
As you can see, the name is duplicated and none is saved inside.
Here is a project from 5 days ago:
enter image description here
As you can see here there is no problem, the folders are in order but if I had the error project by VSCODE this is normal and is the same as in the first image:
enter image description here
I don't know what happens because even when I create a new project from VSCODE and then see it, the new project from Intellij has the same problem as the one in the first photo, I don't know what to do.
My version of the IDE, the community is the 2022.2 edition, I already tried the most recent version but the same error.
Desistale el IDE  como tres veces lo volvi a instalar

what exactly is the error?

Please highlight duplicated names on your screenshot.
